# Python Memory Overflow

Tags: python

Hello my fellow programmers,

I am writing a program which reads 90GB of images into a python list. But my Hardware only has 8GB RAM, thus the program gets stuck. I was wondering if a python list can handle this problem itself by writing on the hard disk or something like that. Otherwise, how could I solve this problem without upgrading the RAM to 128GB?

EDIT: I need to have all images in one list at one time

BACKGROUND INFORMATION: I am making a neural network which colors black and white images

Comment: Use a list to store path to image and load them on-the-fly when needed.

Comment: good idea but thats not applicable in my case. I need to have all images in one list at one time

Comment: Could you please tell us how you are going to use the list afterwards?

Comment: @t_e_o I am iterating through it and use each image for deep learning. (just reading from the list)

Comment: _Why_ do you need all the images at once? You say you are iterating through the list, can't you learn with one image after the other? Explain on more detail what you are doing, and to what end; maybe there's a better way. (e.g., maybe images do not need to be that large for what you intend)

Comment: How are you doing it right now ? Are you using any library for deep learning ?

Comment: I am using PyTorch. I give the list into the Dataloader from PyTorch which requires a list

Comment: Does the method you are using have an argument batch_size or something similar?

Comment: Adding to @tobias_k 's comment, although not sure, but have you considered loading these files in batches with data loaders ? I know that pyTorch supports something similar

Comment: Just thinking, can [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mmap.html) be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it absolutely necessary to have all of the images in the memory at the same time? You could either process the images in batches or adjust the pipeline to use one image at a time.

You can also use a swap partition to supply additional memory for your process.

Comment: So Python can not handle that itself?

Comment: Your operation system needs to supply a swap patition for python to use. This can easily be done on linux operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) there's an argument batch_size which should help you:

> batch_size (int, optional) – how many samples per batch to load
>   (default: 1).

Comment: The programs gets stuck way before, when i write the images into the list

Comment: Would this be useful then? - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loading-huge-data-functionality/346/2